# How to reload a route using hasher.js and crossroads.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, routes

I currently have this code:

```
crossroads.addRoute('/login', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/login',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {

        },
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#' + main_window).html(msg);
        }
    })
});
```

Along with this hasher.js for maintaining history:

```
function parseHash(newHash, oldHash){
    crossroads.parse(newHash);
}
hasher.initialized.add(parseHash); //parse initial hash
hasher.changed.add(parseHash); //parse hash changes
hasher.init(); //start listening for history change

$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    hasher.setHash($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Now when I have a link that says #/login and click it, the login page is loaded fine. However, if the user clicks the login link again, the page doesn't reload. I know the click is registering, but the routing/hashing isn't firing. How do I manage to do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not changing anything with `hasher.setHash("#/currentpage")` because you are already on that page. So the change event never gets fired. You could probably just go:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    hasher.setHash('');
    hasher.setHash($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

But that would clutter the history, so you could force a reload on the click, if you make the loading method available:

```
var loadLogin = function(){
    $.ajax({
        .... your ajax settings ....
    });
};
crossroads.addRoute('/login', loadLogin);

$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var newHash = $(this).attr('href');
    if(newHash === '/login' && hasher.getHash() === '/login') {
        loadLogin()
    } else {
        hasher.setHash(newHash);
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT**
As @Patchesoft pointed out, crossroads has a property called `ignoreState`, which will force any request to go though the router function, even if on the current page - https://millermedeiros.github.io/crossroads.js/#crossroads-ignoreState

Comment: Is there anyway to make it more general... like do it for all links instead of just the login route?

Comment: Also I found this setting: crossroads.ignoreState= true; allows me to refresh the same route for anyone else stuck on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your can force the call of your route by this:

```
// add this dummy route first
crossroads.addRoute('noop', function() { } );

$('a').on('click', function(e) {
// route to dummy route
hasher.setHash('noop');
// and then replace by your login route
hasher.replaceHash('login');
}
```