# How to refresh content when using CrossroadJS and HasherJS with KnockoutJS

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, knockout-3.0, crossroadsjs

I was following [Lazy Blogger](https://sumitmaitra.wordpress.com/2014/08/04/part-3-ko-components-routes-and-hashes/) for getting started with routing in knockoutJS using crossroads and hasher and it worked correctly.
Now I needed to refresh the content using ajax for Home and Settings page every time they are clicked. So I googled but could not find some useful resources. Only these two links

1. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386060/how-to-reload-a-route-using-hasher-js-and-crossroads-js) Here I could not understand where to place the ignoreState property and tried these. But could not make it work.

   ```
       define(["jquery", "knockout", "crossroads", "hasher"], function ($, ko, crossroads, hasher) {

       return new Router({
           routes:
           [
               { url: '', params: { page: 'product' } },
               { url: 'log', params: { page: 'log' } }
           ]
       });

       function Router(config) {
           var currentRoute = this.currentRoute = ko.observable({});

           ko.utils.arrayForEach(config.routes, function (route) {
               crossroads.addRoute(route.url, function (requestParams) {
                   currentRoute(ko.utils.extend(requestParams, route.params));
               });
           });
           activateCrossroads();
       }

       function activateCrossroads() {
           function parseHash(newHash, oldHash) {
               //crossroads.ignoreState = true; First try
               crossroads.parse(newHash);
           }
           crossroads.normalizeFn = crossroads.NORM_AS_OBJECT;

           hasher.initialized.add(parseHash);
           hasher.changed.add(parseHash);
           hasher.init();

           $('a').on('click', function (e) {
               crossroads.ignoreState = true; //Second try
           });

       }
   });
   ```
2. [Crossroads Official Page](https://millermedeiros.github.io/crossroads.js/#crossroads-ignoreState) Here too I could not find where this property need to be set.

If you know then please point me to some url where I can get more details about this.

Comment: There are two video courses on knockout from John Papa - http://www.johnpapa.net/2forfree/ ( not free anymore though). check it out. he talk about routing in details.

Comment: @vittore thanks for sharing the video course. Do you know any free resource so that can help me out?

Comment: How about a video from Knockout's creator? [https://vimeo.com/97519516](https://vimeo.com/97519516)